# Does Task<T> actually lower the number of threads used?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, task

I'm researching performance improvements for a WCF web service. This web service calls other web services that can take a long time to respond (5+ seconds). With high load on our service we can experience a situation where all threads are used because they are waiting for the downstream service to respond. This causes the whole system to backup, etc.

So I'm researching if using the WCF async Task pattern will actually help out here. My real question is what exactly happens to the thread calling the downstream service wile it's waiting for a response? Is that thread still allocated to the call, just in a background worker pool or something? I need to be able to prove that moving to async Tasks will actually lower the number of threads used, if it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want here is to return your long-running thread to the thread pool and execute what is called a completion to have that thread pick up the response... Basically your goal should be to have a thread handle the incoming request to your service, then call out to the long-waiting external service, near-immediately returning to the thread pool to be available for other requests to your service. Then upon notification that the third party service response is ready, it *or a different thread* from the thread pool will be allocated to grab the response and process it.

The Task framework is more for parallelization and less for thread pool based completions / tailing patterns. It spawns a thread to do some work, but unless you manually intervene in fairly advanced ways, said thread won't return to the pool between long-running calls. What you could look into instead is the async pattern calls: Begin/End syntax.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.100).aspx

These methods / completions will release the thread to the pool while awaiting the response, which should free said thread up to handle more of your service's calls.

If you're using .NET 4.5, the async/await keywords are a pretty wrapper for this pattern, and you could use those instead.

Comment: great info. So out of curiosity is there like a single thread that is listening for the response? I mean something must open a TCP socket, and keep listening for the final response, right? What is that? Does it use a single thread (or fixed pool of threads) to share between all connections it's listening for?

Comment: Generally that is the pattern, yes. One or more threads share the port and listen in a loop, when they get a response they immediately spin it off on a thread and go back to listening.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're hosted on ASP.NET. In that case, when a method is performing an `await`, the request thread is fully returned to the thread pool and is free to handle other requests.

The easiest way to test this is to limit the threads on your server side:

```
int workerThreads, ioThreads;
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out ioThreads);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(Environment.ProcessorCount, ioThreads);
```

and set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to `int.MaxValue` in a client tester that performs `Environment.ProcessorCount + 1` simultaneous requests.

I have a WebAPI example of this test [here](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/5796697). It shouldn't be difficult to convert it to a WCF example.